# Error while running MPI cluster program in LAN

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, mpi, mpich, mpiexec

Getting error while running MPI cluster program in a LAN environment. I have created a master and other clients in a local LAN environment. I follow this tutorial to create a cluster and runs it, [Running an MPI Cluster with in LAN](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/)

**mpiuser@507-12**:~/cloud/mpich-3.0.4/examples$ **mpirun -np 4 -hosts 192.168.100.77, 192.168.100.78 ./icpi**

```
mpirun: Error: unknown option "-o" Type 'mpirun --help' for usage.
```

It's saying that we should use proper tags while writing the command and then it will work. But, I tried many ways to run it by changing or altering the tags. Still getting the same error. Couldn't figure out whats going wrong. Kindly, help me in due respect. Thanks.

Comment: You have a space between the two ip addresses. Remove that. Format is `-hosts ip1,ip2`

Comment: Still the error persist. Didn't understood properly.

Comment: Looks like -hosts is parsed as a multi character option, just try -h  or not specifying the hosts at all. Or RTFM: What does "man mpirun" say? Or "mpirun --help" for that matter? Maybe you are executing another version of mpirun than you think?

Comment: yes version I am running was different. Now it works. Thanks for your response. @GeorgBisseling

Answer (score 2):

The option -hosts should be -host (alias -H, --host)