# Error running openMPI on linux cluster

Tags: openmpi, mpich

I have trouble running MPI code on cluster and use the following command to run the code and tried it with ip addresses as well.

```
mpiuser1@comp-asdf-4:~$ mpirun -np 4 -hosts master, slave1 ./myexe
```

and have following error

```
mpirun: Error: unknown option "-o"
Type 'mpirun --help' for usage.
```

i have a cluster of 2 nodes one master and slave and  I follow this tutorial http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/  to create a cluster. I am using ubuntu (16.04.1), gcc version 5.4.0, openmpi version 3.0.1. The same error reported by other user but he wasn't using the same version of mpi on all cluster nodes and have tried the suggesstions posted here [Error while running MPI cluster program in LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042475/error-while-running-mpi-cluster-program-in-lan) but problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying hosts with OpenMPI works with `--host`. This is a bit different than with MPICH2 used in the tutorial you follow.

```
$ mpirun -np 4 --host master, slave1 ./myexe
```

I recommend you pay close attention to Open MPI man pages and FAQ.

- [mpirun(1) man page (version 3.0.1)](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man1/mpirun.1.php)
- [How do I specify the hosts on which my MPI job runs?](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpirun-specify-hosts)